# Watching and limiting size of array in angularjs scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

The premise of what I am trying to do is to have a simple Q&A system that shows only one question at a time. After each answer is given another question is presented until $scope.quiz is exhausted.

So far it correctly displays the questions and appends both the question and answer to an array $scope.answers.

I need to somehow know and limit when the questions are exhausted so I can prepare a results page. I was thinking that somehow this should be done in the scope rather than the template but am unsure how to watch the $scope.answers array in real time so I know when it hits it's last question, and from there how to then replace the question div with some results.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Thank you

```
            <div id="q" class="cta1_content ugh" ng-controller="testYourself">
                <div ng-init="count=0">
                    <div ng-repeat="data in quiz" ng-show="data.id==count">
                        <h2 class="text-center">{{data.name}}</h2>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 text-center yesno">
                            <a href="#dropdown" class="q" ng-click="$parent.count=$parent.count+1;addAnswer(count, 1)">
                                <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center yesno">
                            <a href="#dropdown" class="q" ng-click="$parent.count=$parent.count+1;addAnswer(data.id, 0)">
                                <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-close-round"></i></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


app.controller('testYourself', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.quiz = [
 {id:0, name:"q1", answer: [{0: 'a1', 1: 'a2'}], weight:25},
 {id:1, name:"q2", answer: [{0: 'a1', 1: 'a2'}], weight:25},
 ];
 $scope.answers = [];
 $scope.addAnswer = function(q, a) {
    $scope.answers.push({'question':q, 'answer':a});
 };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply replace your addAnswer question with the following :

```
$scope.switchToResults = false;
$scope.proceeed = function(q, a) {
    $scope.answers.push({'question':q, 'answer':a});
    if ($scope.answers.length === $scope.quiz.length) {
        switchToResults = true;
        // do some business logic to process results
    }
}
```

And add `ng-if="!switchToResults"` to your quiz div, and `ng-if="!switchToResults"` to your result div.

Comment: Thank you. Been staring at this code for so long I had totally missed that :-)